# Double clicking delay too short on 20.04

Tags: command-line, partitioning, 20.04, doubleclick, click-policy

I'm new to Ubuntu and on installing focal fossa 20.04, my double-clicking is not working, and I have not been able to double-click easily into a file, I have to right-click enter into a file.

Comment: There is a "Test Your Settings" button at the right - top of **Gnome Settings > Mouse & Touchpad**. Did you test your mouse there?

Answer (score 3):

Gu to Settings → Universal Access → Double-Click Delay

Reduce the value of Double-click delay according to your convenience and check whether the mouse Double-click is working or not. Continue this action till you are able to perform double-click.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a "Test Your Settings" button at the right - top of **Gnome Settings > Mouse & Touchpad**. You can test your mouse double click speed there.

The default mouse double click speed is 400 ms. However, you can changes this with `dconf-editor`. Go to */ org / gnome / settings-daemon / peripherals / mouse / double-click* and enter a "Custom value" that fits your needs.